# Bootstrap to Statistically Compare Accuracy of Different Approaches

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, random-forest, bootstrap, resampling

I am currently dealing with a multi-class classification problem. I have two different approaches (in terms of feature engineering) to this problem. Intuitively, the result is obvious. However, I want to show it statistically.

I use random forest algorithm. The sample size is approximately 750, and the number of predictors is 200 and 150, respectively. The additional 50 variables are relevant, but coming from a different domain compared to the initial 150 I have.

I plan to bootstrap on train sets, determine the best hyperparameters, and compare accuracy distributions for the best hyperparameters.

Statistically, is there anything wrong? Should I train/test split before bootstrap? Is it ok to use all datasets in bootstrap? Do you have any recommendations to improve or make the process statistically more rigorous?

Comment: what do you mean by accuracy?  How do you compute it?

Comment: @EngrStudent I mean overall accuracy, Kappa, or F_Score estimated by caret in R in bootstrapping. So, one of the out-of-bag performance metrics mentioned.

Comment: I like the kappa because it is about agreement between raters. Personally I like to use the Boruta package because I can say "permutation importance says these are important".  You need to make sure to have a train-test split where the model never sees "test" at all during training, and it is used to estimate performance in the presence of new data.  You can repeat 100 times for random splits in the training then first look at variation in non-trained fold, then second test against the, pre-separated and never-touched, test to see how it fits in the distribution.

Comment: @EngrStudent Thank you very much for your answer. I have a question. Is the pre-separated and never-touched test set really helping in this case? I am considering two things: 1-my sample size is not very big, 2- in every 100 iterations, the dataset is split. As a result, for a given iteration, the model never sees the test-set in that iteration. Therefore, does it make sense to not make the "second" test you mention and benefit from using the full-sample size in each iteration? Thank you.

Comment: In the theory there is "in the limit of infinite samples" but the real world imposes constraints that are more aggressive.  I would look at leave-k-out cross-validation, but I would also be very very cautious of overfitting.  I like somewhere between 5 and 35 times as many samples as I do parameters in the fit as a first rule of thumb.  I would randomly split into train/test at 90/10, fit the model using train, test using test, store test value, and then repeat something like 100 times.  I would look at the variation in the score across replicates as well as its mean.

Comment: @EngrStudent Thank you. I have two questions: 1- Why do you prefer repeated train/test, over bootstrap in this case? Is there a specific reason? 2- Do you mean 5 and 35 times as many samples as I do "features" in the fit, instead of parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135495/discussion-between-engrstudent-and-enes).